# How to set a title with line break in Asset Studio?

Tags: android-studio, icons

I'm trying to create an icon through the Asset Studio interface with the **Text** option but I need the text to have a line break. Is this possible?

I want the text to be displayed like:

```
APP
TITLE
```

[image]

Comment: It does not appear that it is possible. I filed [a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/131976524) for it. You could create your two-line text in another graphics tool, then use the Image option to pull that in as the basis for your launcher icon.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking of also creating the feature request. Yeah, that's what I'm searching right now, I'll try to create the two-line text as a separate image and If I succeed I'll update the question to let others know the solution (for now).

Comment: I think may be able to use html break <br>. Not sure it works on titles but works everywhere else like text view string etc.

Comment: The feature request claims that the issue is fixed. To me, it seems not be the case. No \n, <br> nor pasting multiline text seems to yield the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [comment on the feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/131976524#comment4), inserting a line break becomes possible in Android Studio 4. At the time of writing this answer, the latest [Android Studio version](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases) is 3.6 (February 2020).

Answer (score 0):

As per the feature request, it is mentioned that the option for multi line text image asset is available as part of Android Studio 4.0 Version.
Though the current version is 3.x as of now, 4.x is available as stable Beta.
Those who need this feature now can download Android Studio Beta version and access this option.